# how to error Cannot bind to the new display member. Parameter name: newDisplayMember

Tags: c#, combobox

This is my code and when called this function return error:

`Cannot bind to the new display member.Parameter name: newDisplayMember`

Code:

```
public void FillDrpKala()
    {
        string SQL = "SELECT [kID],[kName] FROM tblKala ORDER BY kName";
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(objCon.StrCon))
        {
            using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(SQL, cn))
            {
                cn.Open();

                try
                {
                    adapter.Fill(ds);
                }
                catch (SqlException e)
                {

                    MessageBox.Show("There was an error accessing your data of Kala. DETAIL: " + e.ToString());
                }
            }
        }
        cmbKala.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
        cmbKala.DisplayMember = "mName";
        cmbKala.ValueMember = "mID";
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your column names are mixed up.

Instead of

```
cmbKala.DisplayMember = "mName";
cmbKala.ValueMember = "mID";
```

Try this:

```
cmbKala.DisplayMember = "kName";
cmbKala.ValueMember = "kID";
```